# LinqToSql - change table name attribue at runtime?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

When you create a model using LinqToSql, the designer puts an attribute for each table class that looks like

```
[Table(Name=@"dbo.Project")]
```

At design time this is easy to change either manually or using T4 templates.

Can this table attribute be changed at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are baked into the metadata of the class at compile time and I doubt it is possible changing their values at runtime. By the way that's one of the reasons why attribute values should always be constant expressions.